# MS Access: Best way to limit results of a DateDiff() query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

All,

I'm pretty green to Access and VBA in general, so don't be afraid to be thorough. I currently have a table linked to a read-only database that is queried on a regular basis to provide status information on processing at our facility. This query feeds into a continuous form which is shown to our staff. I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out why I can't restrict our ElapsedTime query at the criteria level.

> Datediff("n",([CollectTime],Now())

> Criteria: Is Not Null AND <120

I'm using 120 as a placeholder for what will eventually be a user-defined variable, but even with a single value, it returns all 300-thousand some entries. I'm sure it's something super simple, I just can't figure it out.

If I can't restrict it at the query level, is there a way I can prune the recordset at the form level instead?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff While adding the where clause no longer returns every entry, it doesn't restrict my results any. I tried it at different intervals, different times, different values, running it without any other time criteria--it either returns no values, a list of all the pending specimens w/i a day's frame (the current expected), or the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

You want a `where` clause.  I would recommend:

```
where CollectTime > dateadd("d", -120, date())
```

Note that this switches the logic so `CollectTime` is not an argument to a function.  That makes this index friendly, if you have an index on `CollectTime`.

Comment: Hey, congrats on that 1M rep score! We both joined SO 9 years and 4 months ago and don't even have 2K answers posted... 80K+ answers is ...just wow. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your trouble is, that interval `n` returns *minutes*, not days. And, as you use `Now()` which contains a time part, results may vary through the day. So, use `d` for a *day* count and also the correct syntax:

```
Datediff("d",[CollectTime],Date())
```

That said, if you have an index on `CollectTime`, use the method posted by Gordon.